# How to smoothen the mesh lines of a translucent sphere

Tags: plotting, mesh

This code generates a nice sphere with distorted mesh lines, in the sense that they are not smooth enough. One can clearly see many disjoint lines trying to imitate a curve. I would like a smoothened curve instead for this particular mesh setup.

`ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Phi], 0,  2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> 6, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1.1, 1.1}, 3], PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.2]}, ImageSize -> Large]`

[image]

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Increase the value of `Mesh`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, that would increase the number of curves, instead of the quality of  each curve. I am sorry if that was not clear from the question.

Comment: Well, it does _both_. I am still figuring out how to do one one thing of the two...

Comment: @Nasser, I really want only these many lines otherwise when I add more details to my plot it will look clumsy. Is there any way to increase the quality?

Comment: Okay, you can leave `Mesh - > 6` and add something like `PlotPoints -> 50`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks that does help. Will adding `MaxRecursion -> 3` change much?

Comment: I don't know. Just try.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, okay that seems to improve the quality too. Thanks for the help! Could you please write the answer so that I can accept it and close?

Comment: I got more clear idea from here: [Make A Smoother Or Rougher Plot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/MakeASmootherOrRougherPlot.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Henrik Schumacher pointed out, I had to increase the number of `PlotPoints`. However, including more number of points did not necessarily change the quality a lot after a value; sort of hit a saturation point.

In case of sphere I really could not see a difference between 25 and 50 points, but probably it is too fine to notice without magnifying many times.

```
GraphicsGrid[
 ArrayReshape[
  {Table[
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, 
     {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
     Mesh -> 6, BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1.1, 1.1}, 3], 
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> i, 
     PlotLabel -> StringJoin["PlotPoints: ", ToString[i]]], 
  {i, {Automatic, 10, 25, 50}}]},
 {2, 2}], 
ImageSize -> Full, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

After reading through [Make A Smoother Or Rougher Plot: How Tos](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/MakeASmootherOrRougherPlot.html) helped me realise, I could increase `MaxRecursion` also. But if `PlotPoints` is too low it does not yield any better results.